# Paypal refund adaptive api always give error "NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER"

Tags: mobile-application, paypal-adaptive-payments

Currently i am using UK's PayPal Business account for PayPal adaptive api.

I successfully able to pay via PayPal adaptive api in my mobile app. Now i want to refund payment to sender and i am following the PayPal developer API Doc, i am follow this link for get refund. :- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

I have already put third party permission as mention in doc, still i am not able to refund success. I am always get "NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER" status in response.

Please help me anyone, I try all thing as per research. What is wrong with my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have solved it,

You just get username from API credential after that open paypal sandbox account of your sandbox receiver and put your username into receiver's third party permission.

After you can refund that receiver.